# Почему Linux не ищет so в текущей папке, как dll в Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, dll, so

Когда я собираю программу, содержащую dll и exe в Windows, dll может лежать как в стандартных папках Windows, так и рядом в exe, чтобы exe запустилось. Тот же самый трюк в Linux не прокатывает: .so должна лежать в /usr/lib, чтобы программа её нашла. В лучшем случае в рамках одного сеанса работы в терминале можно добавить путь к текущей папке, куда всё было собрано, в `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Но тогда становится непонятно, как отлаживать программы в Linux? И почему вообще это так сделано? Разве в одной папке у меня не может быть нескольких программ, использующих одну разделяемую библиотеку?

Comment: Вы можете сделать скрипт, который перед запуском программы добавит путь к .so в LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Где-то писали, что существующие правила поиска обусловлены какими-то соображениями безопасности ...

Comment: @avp, ну это же очевидно: что будет, если вдруг пользователь с правами суперпользователя запустит ssh, слинкованный с OpenSSL, находясь в каталоге со специально подготовленным libssl.so?

Comment: @0andriy. а что может помешать руту делать все, что ему захочется (кроме собственного незнания или лени)?

Comment: это сделано ровно из тех же соображений, что и отсутствие текущего каталога в переменной окружения PATH: соображения безопасности. дело в том, что unix-ы — очень небезопасные системы (по сравнению с досом и его наследниками, разумеется). в них даже нормальных антивирусов нет. и если в текущем каталоге общего пользования (а unix-ы — многопользовательские системы для нищебродов, у которых нет денег на собственный комп.) кто-нибудь оставит исполняемый файл (например, `ls`) или библиотеку (например, `libc.so.6`), которые делают что-нибудь нехорошее, то сами понимаете… // вот потому и …

Comment: @avp, ну поменяйте слово суперпользователь на слова «другой пользователь».

Comment: *dll может лежать как в стандартных папках Windows, так и рядом в exe, чтобы exe запустилось* — не всё так просто, если я правильно понимаю [изложенное в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

Comment: у меня принимает so в папке с программой

Comment: @alexander barakin, Вы вроде бы дали исчерпывающий ответ на мой вопрос, зачем же Вы сделали его комментарием?

Comment: табличку «сарказм» придётся прикладывать.

Comment: @alexander barakin, Так уберите оттуда сарказм и напишите ту же суть - я приму ответ и всего делов.

Answer (score 0):

Так сделано по соображенииям безопасности. Ни в коем случае не надо добавлять текущий каталог в LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Посмотрите мануал к gcc и при сборке указывайте явно библиотеки опциями -rpath, -L.