# Как сделать так, чтобы окно терминала не закрывалось при запуске программы через bash-скрипт?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

В ходе поиска ответа на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/912484/285), я сделал, как мне рекомендовали: `Makefile`, помимо собственно программы, генерирует bash-скрипт, который устанавливает `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` в текущую папку и запускает программу. Он работает, если запустить его из консоли в той папке, где находится скрипт. Но если запускать программму через GUI, то невозможно увидеть результат работы программы: она завершается и сразу же закрывается. Я пробовал вставить в конец скрипта `read` - не работает. `sleep` - работает кривовато. Что ещё можно сделать?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/20330/416190

Comment: Спасибо. И что делать с вопросом, раз Вы опять ответили в комментарии?

Comment: Переведите ответ с англоязычной версии сами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод с [англоязычной версии](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal).

В конце скрипта должна быть строка

```
$SHELL
```

[image: Скриншот (Ubuntu)]
Небольшой изъян: поскольку эмулятор терминала не запускает `bash` как свою оболочку, он будет рассматривать его как приложение и отображать предупреждение при попытке закрытия окна терминала:

```
There is still a process running in this terminal
Closing the terminal will kill it.
```

Чтобы отключить это предупреждение, можно выполнить такую команду:

```
gconftool --set /apps/gnome-terminal/global/confirm_window_close --type boolean false
```

Этого не происходит, если использовать `xterm` вместо `gnome-terminal`

Ещё в коммаентарии к оригинальному ответу предлагалось выполнить `exec $SHELL` вместо `$SHELL`, чтобы избежать этого предупреждения. У меня ничего не поменялось от этого, оба варианта работают одинаково.